# Do images in deleted answers stick around forever?

Tags: support, images, imgur

Do images in deleted answers stick around forever?

I think I already know the answer and I think this is a dumb and/or obvious question but I just want to make sure.

I have an answer with SE-uploaded imgur images in it. I intend to delete the answer but link to one of the images in a comment elsewhere. I was just going to use the generated link from the answer, and want to make sure it'll stick around as long as the comment does.

Comment: I guess you mean only imgur images, hosted on SE dedicated account, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't prune any of our images automatically, and I've frequently used the image uploader to upload images and then link to them in comments, never actually posting them in a question or answer in the first place.

The image sticks around once it's uploaded unless we manually go in and delete it.

Comment: Mmm.... prunes.