# What is the retention time of images uploaded to https://i.stack.imgur.com?

Tags: discussion, images, imgur

I sometimes use SO to upload images to i.stack.imgur.com, but without posting any questions. I found this trick very convenient when I need a permalink to previews or thumbnails.

What is the risk that imgur deletes images that are not genuinely in SO questions?

Comment: I don't think these images are ever deleted. But I'm not 100% sure either.

Comment: Similar, assumes that they *are* used on SE somewhere: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229514/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269778/282094

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/) (emphasis mine):

> Alan Schaaf, the man behind Imgur, generously provided us a network-wide “pro” account that keeps any images hosted through our websites around **indefinitely**.

Staff has the option to request deletion of certain images (abusive ones, or ones containing PII), but otherwise it'll be around forever (or until they switch to another image hoster).

Comment: Or until imgur goes down.