# Why did this uploaded image disappear?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, images, imgur

A post on Super User was deleted. Its [final revision](https://superuser.com/revisions/1718696/2) contained an uploaded image, which has since been deleted from Stack Exchange's image host (Imgur):

[image]

Why did this image disappear?

The original image can be found on the [web archive of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20220429205511/https://superuser.com/questions/1718696/identify-google-chrome-extensions):

[image: original image in web archive]

As you can see, the image is not NSFW or offensive in any way.

Comment: Related: [Are the images from deleted posts kept?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229514/786798)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine thanks, that was indeed my recollection that images typically aren't removed.

Comment: Related-2: [Do images in deleted answers stick around forever?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269776/786798)

Comment: Yeah, the image shouldn't have been removed if those old posts are to be believed - probably needs someone on the inside to drop by to answer definitively

Comment: Stack Exchange staff have the ability to delete images stored on the SE Imgur instance. It's generally done on offensive images.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog thanks, this one was inoffensive.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20220429205511/https://superuser.com/questions/1718696/identify-google-chrome-extensions shows the image. Can't see any particular reason the image was deleted, especially since we need to ping a CM to do it

Comment: To close voters: this question was [deemed on-topic by a moderator](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9194720#9194720).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The question was flag deleted as spam or offensive. Because many posts that are spam or rude have problematic images (or people are using our image hosting to host images of themselves that get flag deleted) our system automatically tells imgur to delete images that were in posts deleted through spam or offensive flags.

Comment: Since when was this implemented?

Comment: @Sonic It was implemented around July 2019, then was broken for a while, and was fixed again in May 2021.

Comment: There is possible major drawback to this. In theory, troll can post spam post and put existing valid image in it, for example [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBnkf.jpg) (your current avatar), then have the image deleted when their spam is nuked. Meaning, power to trolls to delete any picture they want. Are there any measures in place against it? Is the deletion reversible somehow? /cc @animuson

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I just checked some deleted spam posts on my sites, and AFAIK, it's not applied to every spam/offensive post. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lImaH.jpg) from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/239046) (Jun 2021) got deleted, but [this image of soccer players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG3O0.jpg) from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/238995) (Jun 2021) and [dunno what this image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hREER.jpg) from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/244507) (Dec 2021) were not deleted.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. weird, if there was some manual check before deletion the image discussed in this question wouldn't have been removed, so maybe it's still broken a bit.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. The current design only detects them if they are formatted as images in the current revision of the post. It won't ever delete images that are merely linked.

Comment: Donno what the current implementation looks like, @shadow, but the original spec required a check against the imgur metadata specifically to reduce risk here: if the image wasn't uploaded within a fairly narrow window of the deleted post's creation, it wouldn't be automatically deleted.

Comment: @Shog9 huh, smart.